# SVN "Comments Browser"

Tags: svn

In SVN, it is possible to enter Messages (or comments) when you create a new branch, tag, etc.
Is there a tool that list all the folders with their comments to generate "doc"?

I need this to keep an history on the tags/branches with all the comments. I do not want all the revisions infos as displayed by the 'Show Log' command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course. `svn copy <source branch> <destination branch> -m"here is my message annotating why I am making this branch"`

> I do not want all the revisions infos as displayed by the 'Show Log' command.

They're the same thing. They're all commit messages. If you want to retrieve just the message corresponding to the creation of that branch, then specify that in your `svn log` command: `svn log -v --stop-on-copy <branch name> | tail`

Comment: Thanks. Adding the --xml option and a pipe I was able to output the resulting messages to an XML file. Whit a simple XSLT it's now pretty human readle and auto-generated.